# navigating markdown documents using ctags with vim and neovim

Tags: ctags, filetype-markdown

I work on my dotfiles periodically throughout my day work or non work related (that bonsai tree that's never done). I've written a couple of markdown documents that have become rather large to navigate in vim and for the most part i just go to the top of the document using <kbd>gg</kbd> in command mode to search for what it is i'm looking for. it works a portion of the time, but it'd be ideal if i could navigate a markdown document `.md` using [universal-ctags](https://ctags.io) as most of the documents i work with have a TOC within them, so popping open the TOC within the document and doing a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to go to the heading under my cursor could become super useful for navigating my markdown documents, (a local wiki of notes i maintain for referencing tips tricks and howto's throughout my day).

universal-ctags comes with some regex matching for `.md` (Markdown) documents out of the box, and i can navigate to a heading that does not have spaces in it.

**Example: markdown document structure**

> git-Notes.md

```
<a id="contents"></a>

## Contents

 - [Gotchas](#git-gotchas)
 - [Useful Links](#useful-links)
```

I move the cursor under `[Gotchas]` and i'm able to move to that particular position in the document using ctags, but if i try to navigate to the `[Useful Links]` section of the document it's a *no go* as I'm pretty sure uctags is running into an issue with the heading containing a *space* within it.

I literally was able to get ctags installed just a few days, and, that was a completely [separate issue upon itself](https://github.com/universal-ctags/homebrew-universal-ctags/issues/23#issuecomment-583781848), but i do have *uctags* installed and working now, but have no idea how it uses regex's to aid in the generation of a `tags` file for a particular project / repo.

Obviously the more information one could provide the better it would be in helping understand what is going on, as I've tried a couple of different regex examples on the internet, and they seem to fail, either in building the `tags` file due to a syntax error thus preventing a `tags` file being generated at all, or they fail in navigating through headings that contain *spaces* in them, ie. *Useful Links*

Comment: What about loading the headers into a quickfix list or interactive menu?

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach (that fails if you have embedded code comments) is to do something like

```
global/^#/#
```

And then type `:` and the displayed line number of the match you want. You could assign the commands to a mapping.

Or, yank the words you want to search and do `/^#\+ <C-r>"`, which could be assigned to an operator for fun: e.g., `ghi]` would take you to the header matching for the words im brackets.

Comment: please excuse my ignorance,

I'm new to ctags and your answer comes across as abstract to me.

Is this a **Vim only** solution? or is this incorporating _ctags_?

And if either is the case? I don't suppose you could put together a visual explanation of your answer by creating an asciicast?

Comment: @ipatch im not sure when I’ll have to put together a video, but yes these are just vim commands. I can try to expand a little later at some point.

Comment: ahhh yeah, that's what i figured, was / am hoping to setup a ctags based regular expression for navigating markdown documents.